# C assignment from incompatible pointer type error

Tags: c, function, pointers, parameter-passing

I am getting incompatible type error at line 14 when passing the pointer of the integer to another function. Can anybody explain me why and how to solve this problem.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int check_similar(int *pa, int *pb);

int main()
{
    int a[5], b[5], i;
    for (i=0; i<5; i++){
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }
    for (i=0; i<5; i++){
        scanf("%d", &b[i]);
    }
    if (check_similar(&a, &b))
        printf("Strictly identical");
    else
        printf("Not identical");
}

int check_similar(int *pa, int *pb)
{
    int i=0;
    while (*(pa+i)==*(pb+i)){
        i++;
    }
    if (i==5)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
```

Comment: Just pass a and b, not &a and &b. a and b will decay from arrays to pointers automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `a` and `b` are defined as:

```
int a[5], b[5]
```

The symbol for each points to the the first element of the array, therefore satisfying the need for passing the *address of* the argument without using the *address of* operator `&` :

```
if (check_similar(&a, &b))
                  ^   ^
```

The *incompatible type error* you are seeing is because by using the `&` operator, the variable types passed are effectively `int *[5]`. (And because array types decay into simple pointer types, the called function sees each argument as `int **`.)  The prototype requires these argument types to be `int *`.

Changing it to the following will address the problem:

```
if (check_similar(a, b))
```

Answer (score 1):

You must pass arrays in check_similar function as it is.

```
check_similar(a,b);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (check_similar(&a, &b))
```

Since arrays, when passed as an argument to a function, decay to a pointer to the first element by default:

> "Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator, or the unary & operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type "array of type" is converted to an expression with type "pointer to type" that points to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object has register storage class, the behavior is undefined."
>
> Source: C18, §6.3.2.1/3

using the `&` operator to that pointer gains a pointer of type `int (*)[5]`, but `check_similar` expects `int *` as arguments.

That is the pointer mismatch, the incompatible pointer error referred to.

---

Simply omit the `&`s:

```
if (check_similar(a, b))
```

and everything is fine.

Answer (score 1):

`a` and `b` are pointers to `a [0]` and `b [0]` respectively. As such, `&a` and `&b` are pointers to pointers to `a [0]` and `b [0]` respectively.